# Ruby 1.9.3 Regexp#==: same pattern, different syntaxes, different equality

Tags: ruby, regex

If I want to write a simple regexp in ruby to match just the slash literal (`/`, U+002F), I can write it using two syntax forms. A slash-delimited literal with a backslash-escaped slash character:

```
/\//
```

or using "percent-r" syntax, where there's no need to escape the slash:

```
%r{/}
```

So, my question: in Ruby 1.9.3, **why do these two "equivalent" regexps not equal each other?**

```
>> /\// == %r{/}
=> false
```

They `match` the same strings:

```
>> /\//.match('/')
=> #<MatchData "/">

>> %r{/}.match('/')
=> #<MatchData "/">
```

They `inspect` the same:

```
>> /\//
=> /\//

>> %r{/}
=> /\//
```

They `to_s` the same:

```
>> /\//.to_s
=> "(?-mix:\\/)"

>> %r{/}.to_s
=> "(?-mix:\\/)"
```

But they don't `hash` the same!

```
>> /\//.hash
=> -913497737416042053

>> %r{/}.hash
=> 1283138729813860088
```

So...what about them is different? It's got something to do with the backslash escape char, since:

```
>> %r{\/} == %r{\/}
=> true

>> %r{/} == %r{\/}
=> false
```

Ruby's [documentation on `Regexp.==`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#3D-3D-method) mumbles something about "character sets" and "pattern" needing to be the same, but helpfully doesn't mention what "character sets" and "pattern" are.

Comment: In Ruby 2.2.1 `/\// == %r{/}` results in `true`. Hashes match as well.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom: Ah, yep. Good call. I was testing these under 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ruby 1.9.3-p551, the [`source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-source) of the two `Regexp` objects is different:

```
1.9.3-p551 :001 > /\//.source
 => "\\/" 
1.9.3-p551 :002 > %r{/}.source
 => "/"
```

`Regexp#==` [compares the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_551/re.c#L2594) when checking for equality.

`Regexp#hash` [includes the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_551/re.c#L2566) in the hash code computation.

With Ruby 2.0.0-p0 and later, the `source` of the slash-delimited literal matches that of the percent-r syntax literal and the two Regexp objects are equal:

```
2.0.0-p0 :001 > /\//.source
 => "/" 
2.0.0-p0 :002 > %r{/}.source
 => "/" 
2.0.0-p0 :003 > /\// == %r{/}
 => true
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks! You don't happen to know which version of ruby changed this behavior, do you?

Comment: @pje It looks like the change happened in Ruby 2.0.0-p0.